# Is it possible to do conditional URL rewrites dependent on user-agent in ASP.NET/IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

The website I work on hosts content that constantly gets scraped and posted elsewhere.

Is is possible to do URL rewrites so normal users and white-listed crawlers can view the website, but block access to unidentifiable browsers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using **URL Rewrite module** (I'm using v2 .. but it should work with v1.x as well, although I have no v1.x around to test):

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="UserAgentRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="(iphone|ipod)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/special-page.aspx" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

With the above rule ALL requests from iPhone or iPad (or any other browser/app that has `iphone` or `ipod` in User Agent String) will be rewritten (internal redirect) to `/special-page.aspx`.

Comment: +1 nice one. Its quite easy to spice in jQuery Mobile on an existing website by using this.

Comment: You should note that that if you offer different content based on a header, then you should add that header to the Vary header. So you should also add the header "Vary: User-Agent".

Answer (score 2):

If someone really wants to scrape your content i guess its only a matter of time till he adapts his technice to fake an allowed browser. Still serving different content per user agent is a nice feature to explore.

Comment: I was actually planning on doing something a little more subtle and elaborate. Changing different insignificant portions of the content to those suspicious browsers and see where each end up. Eventually when I've narrowed down the culprit, I'll change every "buy" to "sell", "up" to "down, "stocks" to "bacon", and add a random amount to each number in the article. Hopefull the scraper won't catch on.