# is it possible to apply URL rewrite rule only to IE browsers on Windows XP?

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have the following URL rewrite rule currently (thanks to [smarx's post](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/redirecting-to-https-in-windows-azure-two-methods)):

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

it redirects all HTTP traffic to HTTPS - so all sites are secured right away. For some reasons (SNI, Azure, Windows XP - it's complicated - read [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1192170.aspx) if you want) I need to keep HTTP for Windows XP IE browsers. Is it possible to do in web.config? If yes - how would I do it? I guess I need to inspect HTTP headers, but how?..

I'm using II8 & ASP.NET MVC4 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  See this question for more details and example code:  [Is it possible to do conditional URL rewrites dependent on user-agent in ASP.NET/IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689436/is-it-possible-to-do-conditional-url-rewrites-dependent-on-user-agent-in-asp-net)

```
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="YOUR_REGEX_HERE" />
            </conditions>
```

Answer (score 2):

technically Robert's answer is correct - i just want to share the exact regex I came up with:

```
    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^(?=.*?MSIE)(?=.*?Windows NT 5\.).*$" negate="true" />
```

that will exclude Windows XP IE browsers from my rule.